# Regex for date validation

Tags: java, regex

I am using the following regex to validate a date in java:

```
"^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-./](0?[1-9]|1[012])[-./]((19|20)\\d\\d)$"
```

But it is also taking the the formats like 21-12.2014 or 21.12/2014 as valid date. I know that this is because I used `[-./]` in my regex. How can I avoid this problem?

Comment: Don't use regex? (E.g., use a date-parsing library.) Easier to maintain and understand later.

Comment: Agreed with @DaveNewton.  Don't use a regex for this.  It'll get completely unwieldy before it captures all of the possibilities that you need.  It'll be much easier to read if you say "dd-MM-yyyy".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you need to use  back-reference.

```
"^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])([-./])(0?[1-9]|1[012])\\2((19|20)\\d\\d)$"
```

`\\2` in the above regex refers to the characters present inside the group index 2.

**NOTE:** Don't parse dates with regex.

**Example:**

```
String s1 = "21-12-2014";
String s2 = "21-12/2014";
System.out.println(s1.matches("^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])([-./])(0?[1-9]|1[012])\\2((19|20)\\d\\d)$"));
System.out.println(s2.matches("^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])([-./])(0?[1-9]|1[012])\\2((19|20)\\d\\d)$"));
```

**Output:**

```
true
false
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a regex at all.  Just parse the date, since you're obviously about to do that anyway.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
Date d = sdf.parse(dateStr.replaceAll("[./]", "-"));
```

Catch the exception for the invalid date.